# UIStackView items width issue in iOS 15.0

Tags: ios, swift, horizontal-scrolling, uistackview

I have two items inside the stackView, width for both the items(Buttons) depends on the text size with horizontal scroll. In iOS 15.5+ devices its working fine where as in below 15.5 its width stretching for both the items. I have set below stack view properties in Xcode

**Alignment - Fill**

**Distribution - Fill proportionally**

**spacing - 8**

Attaching both the screenshot below

**in iOS 15.5 +**

[image]

**In iOS 15**
[image]

[image]

**Source of the Storyboard(Only storyboard no code at all)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="21507" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
    <device id="retina6_12" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="21505"/>
        <capability name="Named colors" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModule="HorizontalScroll" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="393" height="852"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <scrollView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" showsHorizontalScrollIndicator="NO" showsVerticalScrollIndicator="NO" indicatorStyle="white" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="pPz-B2-Rzp">
                                <rect key="frame" x="9" y="134" width="375" height="28"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <stackView contentMode="scaleAspectFill" distribution="fillProportionally" spacing="8" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="38d-tZ-Ob8">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="8" y="0.0" width="551" height="28"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" contentHorizontalAlignment="leading" contentVerticalAlignment="fill" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="9yA-Gf-ewo">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="8" y="0.0" width="157.33333333333334" height="28"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.66666666669999997" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                                <color key="tintColor" white="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                                <state key="normal" title="Button"/>
                                                <buttonConfiguration key="configuration" style="plain" image="square.and.arrow.up.fill" catalog="system" imagePlacement="leading" title="Left not as right" imagePadding="10">
                                                    <fontDescription key="titleFontDescription" name="FidelitySans-Regular" family="Fidelity Sans" pointSize="14"/>
                                                </buttonConfiguration>
                                                <userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
                                                    <userDefinedRuntimeAttribute type="number" keyPath="cornerRadius">
                                                        <real key="value" value="15"/>
                                                    </userDefinedRuntimeAttribute>
                                                </userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
                                            </button>
                                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="center" semanticContentAttribute="forceRightToLeft" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="hg7-VQ-pG3">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="173.33333333333334" y="0.0" width="369.66666666666663" height="28"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.66666666666666663" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                                <color key="tintColor" white="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                                <inset key="imageEdgeInsets" minX="0.0" minY="0.0" maxX="10" maxY="0.0"/>
                                                <state key="normal" title="Button" image="header_down_arrow_active"/>
                                                <buttonConfiguration key="configuration" style="plain" image="rectangle.portrait.and.arrow.forward.fill" catalog="system" title="Right Button width is dynamic based on the title" imagePadding="10">
                                                    <fontDescription key="titleFontDescription" name="FidelitySans-Regular" family="Fidelity Sans" pointSize="14"/>
                                                </buttonConfiguration>
                                                <userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
                                                    <userDefinedRuntimeAttribute type="number" keyPath="cornerRadius">
                                                        <real key="value" value="15"/>
                                                    </userDefinedRuntimeAttribute>
                                                </userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
                                            </button>
                                        </subviews>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" constant="300" id="bBu-9U-0sf"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                        <edgeInsets key="layoutMargins" top="0.0" left="8" bottom="0.0" right="8"/>
                                    </stackView>
                                </subviews>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" name="hlo-white"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="38d-tZ-Ob8" secondAttribute="bottom" id="DzN-fS-Ej7"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="28" id="EvL-B8-0B9"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="38d-tZ-Ob8" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="pPz-B2-Rzp" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="eJW-wz-W4i"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="38d-tZ-Ob8" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="pPz-B2-Rzp" secondAttribute="top" id="qSq-Ub-rYd"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="38d-tZ-Ob8" secondAttribute="trailing" id="uve-dX-nuu"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="38d-tZ-Ob8" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="pPz-B2-Rzp" secondAttribute="centerY" id="w5w-1X-may"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </scrollView>
                        </subviews>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="6Tk-OE-BBY"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="pPz-B2-Rzp" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="leading" constant="9" id="jpM-Ag-u78"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="pPz-B2-Rzp" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="top" constant="75" id="kx9-AK-3lD"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="pPz-B2-Rzp" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="centerX" id="nTS-yX-v1j"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-108" y="4"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <image name="header_down_arrow_active" width="20" height="11"/>
        <image name="rectangle.portrait.and.arrow.forward.fill" catalog="system" width="128" height="108"/>
        <image name="square.and.arrow.up.fill" catalog="system" width="115" height="128"/>
        <namedColor name="hlo-white">
            <color red="0.32899999618530273" green="0.32400000095367432" blue="0.4779999852180481" alpha="0.33000001311302185" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
        </namedColor>
        <systemColor name="systemBackgroundColor">
            <color white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```

Comment: Bro code matters..Are u using SwiftUI or Storyboard?

Comment: @OhStack - what constraints do you have on your stack view? Leading/Trailing? Width?

Comment: @DonMag, Trailing/leading to superview, and width >= 300 to the scrollview. I mean there is scrollview -> stack view

Comment: @OhStack - you'll need to provide a little more information... preferably, a [mre] so we can see what's going on. This is what I get on a quick test: https://i.stack.imgur.com/su1fu.png

Comment: @DonMag I am able reproduce find the screenshots attached for constraints which I have applied https://imgur.com/a/Zu1NeNJ. not able to upload demo project because security reason

Comment: @OhStack - can't tell from your screen shots... Post your Storyboard to a file-sharing site, or edit your question and include the Source of the Storyboard. Also, your buttons at run-time do not look like they do in your Storyboard screen shots, so include any code that is changing them.

Comment: @DonMag, I have added the source of the storyboard in the question hope it helps. There is no code at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has made a number of changes over the years in an attempt to make UI elements "more readable" and to make layouts "more uniform."

Here (and I've seen this in other situations), it appears UIKit sizes the buttons in unexpected ways.

You can fix this specific issue by Requiring both Content Hugging and Content Compression Resistance on both buttons:

[image]

Comment: this worked. Even I tried with hugging and compression but not the perfect priority. Thank you